# Image Slider (Daimajia) using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, slider, firebase-realtime-database

Am trying to load picture and text on the slider from firebase into `daimajia` slider , but nothing is showing , am using a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` , this is how am doing it in the method below :-.

**But i have alreday declared**

```
sliderShow = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
```

**in the `onCreate` method**

```
 public void GetAdverts()
    {


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Advert,MainActivity.EventViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter_ = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Advert, MainActivity.EventViewHolder>(Advert.class,
                R.layout.slider_image,
                MainActivity.EventViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MainActivity.EventViewHolder viewHolder, final Advert model, final int position) {

            try{


                HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                List<Advert> itemlist = new ArrayList<>();


                url_maps.put(model.getTitle(), model.getImageAdvert());


                for(String name : url_maps.keySet()){
                    TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getApplicationContext());
                    // initialize a SliderLayout
                    textSliderView
                            .description(name)
                            .image(url_maps.get(name));
                    //add your extra information
                    textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                    textSliderView.getBundle()
                            .putString("extra",name);
                    textSliderView.setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "News Details ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                    sliderShow.addSlider(textSliderView);
                }

                //   sliderShow.addSlider(textSliderView);
                sliderShow.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
                sliderShow.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
                sliderShow.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
                sliderShow.setDuration(10000);


            }
            catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            }
        };


    }
```

where am i wrong please.

**My Updated code.**

```
 void Slider(){

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Map<String, Advert> td = new HashMap<String, Advert>();


            HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();        

            ArrayList<Advert> values = new ArrayList<>(td.values());

           // List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(td.keySet());

            for (Advert ad: values) {

              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ad.getImageAdvert(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                url_maps.put(ad.getTitle(),ad.getImageAdvert());


            }

            for(String name : url_maps.keySet()){
                TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getApplicationContext());
                // initialize a SliderLayout
                textSliderView
                        .description(name)
                        .image(url_maps.get(name));
                //add your extra information
                textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                textSliderView.getBundle()
                        .putString("extra",name);
                textSliderView.setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Advertise Here ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                sliderShow.addSlider(textSliderView);
            }

            //   sliderShow.addSlider(textSliderView);
            sliderShow.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
            sliderShow.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
            sliderShow.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
            sliderShow.setDuration(10000);


        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    sliderShow = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
}
```

**My Advert Class.**

```
public class Advert {

public String ImageAdvert;
public String  Title;


public Advert() {

    // left out for firebase ...

}


public String getImageAdvert() {
    return ImageAdvert;
}

public void setImageAdvert(String imageAdvert) {
    ImageAdvert = imageAdvert;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is ment to set the data inside FirebaseRecycler!

If you want to simply get the data from DatabaseReference you should use Listeners.

[FirebaseDatabse - Retrieving Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

> To read data at a path and listen for changes, use the addValueEventListener() oraddListenerForSingleValueEvent() method to add a ValueEventListener to a DatabaseReference.

(There is also a third listener for Child - [ChildEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data))

Comment: @ yotam , yeah i understand your concept but i have tried also this check out my post i have updated it but it also shows null

Comment: Upload Advert and MainActivity.EventViewHolder code. ALSO make sure you Reference to the right place and that there is no problem with the rules.

Comment: i used `addValueEventListener()` , but it also shows null man

Comment: i watched your listener, and you dotn use DataSnapshot???
DataSnapshot is where the values are

Comment: So i got rid of the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter coz i see its irrelevant , `addValueEventListener()` , is right as you said but  i dont know if the way am trying to get the list is coorect , check out my `Slider`  especially this line

Comment: `for (Advert ad: values) {

              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ad.getImageAdvert(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                url_maps.put(ad.getTitle(),ad.getImageAdvert());


            }`

Comment: @ yotam , please if you dont mind show me how i can use the results in the `DataSnapShot`

Comment: Man it will be my pleasure if you help me on this @yotam

Comment: Well the reference is of List of Advert? uplaod picture of the firebase list (to where the reference point to)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use two activities (first activity = VoidActivity and second activity = MainActivty), for VoidActivty to take data from firebase database then send it to MainActivity using SharedRefrence or intent.putString

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use two activities (first activity = VoidActivity and second activity = MainActivty), VoidActivty retrieve data from the firebase database then send it to MainActivity using SharedPefrence or use intent.putString (), it runs for me